# Value-Function VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function evaluation_frequency(device As Range, tester As Range, tester_config As Range, Optional tester_name As Range) As String
  If InStr("FREQUENCY", tester_name.Value) <> 0 Then
    Exit Function
  Else
    If tester = "Y" Then
      If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(WorksheetFunction.Search(tester_config, device)) = True Then
        Set evaluation_frequency = "run"
        Exit Function
      Else Call evaluation_frequency(device, tester.Offset(i + 1, 0), tester_name.Offset(i + 1, 0))
      End If
    Else
      Call evaluation_frequency(device, tester.Offset(i + 1, 0), tester_name.Offset(i + 1, 0))
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

When I insert this function inside a range in excel, the code doesn't work and popped an Object required error specifically at this line `Set evaluation_frequency = "run"`. Then I changed to the function type from String to Range and also `Set evaluation_frequency.Value = "run"`, which will give the result I want.

Here is the snippet of how it looked on the Worksheet.

[image: Example]

What I want: instead of changing the value of the range to a fix one word, which in my function is "run", the function will add the word "run" on the existing value of that range. Or in other words, it can be used with other function and the range or cell can both store the output of the function evaluation_frequency and other function.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to add a screenshot of what you expect for output given your input data. Note that the `Set` keyword is used to set a variable to an object. In your code as posted, neither side of the equation is an object. Also please post your data as text which can be copy/pasted. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Remove the `Set` in `Set evaluation_frequency = "run"` - `Set` is used to assign an Object, but your function is of type `String`

Comment: @FunThomas already made the changes. But why it shows #VALUE error

Comment: Probably  `#VALUE`  is displayed because inside the function a runtime error occurs. You should try to debug the function so see where the error happens.

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587) As instructed in [ask], can you please describe your problem **_before_** showing code?